# JS - confirmbox inside a function

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript who works well, because yesterday i get here some very good solutions.
I want to know if i can extended this Javascript with another Query.
The query now, gives an alert when the number is bigger then 199. It works well.

But now i want to know, if i can get confirmbox inside for the same inputbox, when i write a number bigger then 100?
Here an example
I write the number 110 and i does get an confirm box with an Information(bla bla), and when i click Yes this number stays in the inputbox.
But when i write 200 or bigger then i does get the alert that this number is to big.
Here the code, what i get yesterday, whenn the number is bigger then 199:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function minMax() {
       var min = 0;
       var mid = 99;
       var max = 199;
       var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('value_one').value);
       if (num > mid && num < max) {
           var r = confirm(num + ' n\'is greater than ' + mid+ '. Press Yes to retain it.');
           if (r == false) document.getElementById('value_one').value = "";
           return false;
       }
       if (min > num || max < num) {
           alert(num + ' n\'is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
           return false;
       }       
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form>
            Value: <input type='text' id="value_one"  onBlur="minMax();">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is it possible and if somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `confirm` box for this instead of `alert`. Check the demo it on [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm).

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function minMax() {
       var min = 0;
       var mid = 100;
       var max = 199;
       var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('value_one').value);
       if (num > mid && num < max) {
           var r = confirm(num + ' n\'is greater than ' + mid+ '. Press Yes to retain it.');
           if (r == false) document.getElementById('value_one').value = "";
           return false;
       }
       if (min > num || max < num) {
           alert(num + ' n\'is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
           return false;
       }       
   } 
</script>
```

Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FqhRX/) on jsFiddle.net.

Hope this works out for you.

Comment: @achillix Welcome to SO. Seen you have asked a question earlier and is satisfied with answer provided. On SO, you need to accept answers for your question. Please read the FAQ for more information. This helps others who are facing similar issue in identifying the answer which helped you.

Comment: it Works perfect on jsFiddle. But when i take the same code into my page, then it doesn't works. I will updated my question. I have IE6 !

Comment: Sorry, it works great now, i have make an mistake. Thank you very much Amar. You saved my day ;-) cheers

Comment: @achillix. Sorry but I missed out the closing braces for my function. Updated my answer. try it now.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Below Up and Down vote, there is icon of "Correct Answer", on clicking which you can accept answer. Please do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `confirm` box you can control it based on the option you selected(yes or cancel).

You can also make the textbox clean when it cross the max (`document.getElementById('value_one').value=0`)

Comment: Learn to format your answer. It helps other to read it easily.

Comment: Taht is very good and usefull to clean the textbos, thank you, but there i need also an alert.
THX